# Insert/select an encrypted string to/from Postgres using Qt not working properly

Tags: c++, postgresql, qt

In this program I need to encrypt a plain text string, insert the encrypted string into a Postgres table with a bytea column, and later retrieve the encrypted data, decrypt it and get the original string back. I have learned during my research that the encrypted data should be stored as binary data in Postgres database, and the recommended format is [bytea Hex Format](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-binary.html)

Here is what I tried, I want to see if the encryption/decryption work correctly so I add some debug code to write some output to a log file

```
bool BaseDAO::insertIntoDb (const DataObject &data)
{
  QVariantMap dataMap = data.toQVariantMap();
  QString rows = getFieldsStringForSql(dataMap);
  QString placeholders = getPlaceholderStringForSql(dataMap);

  QSqlQuery query = DatabaseDriver::getInstance().prepareQuery(
    "INSERT INTO " + getTableName() + " " + rows + " VALUES " + placeholders
  );
  bindValuesToQuery(query, dataMap);
  query.exec();
  
  // the following are the debug code
  QString sql = "SELECT name FROM student WHERE idx = ?";
  QSqlQuery q = DatabaseDriver::getInstance().prepareQuery(sql);
  q.addBindValue(m_idx.getValue());
  q.exec();
  QSqlRecord rec = q.record();
  QVariant cipher = rec.value("name");

  // StringUtil::fromQString convert a QString to a std::string
  LOGS_INFO_PUB("encrypted string: " << StringUtil::fromQString(cipher.toString()));

  QByteArray byteArray = QByteArray::fromHex(cipher.toByteArray());
  std:string studentName = std::string(byteArray.constData(), byteArray.length());
  
  // BlowfishEncrypter has encrypt and decrypt function
  // both take std::string as parameber and return a std::string
  LOGS_INFO_PUB("student name is: " << BlowfishEncrypter.decrypt(studentName));
  ...
}


void BaseDAO::bindValuesToQuery(QSqlQuery& query, const QVariantMap& data) const
{
  const QVariantList valueList = data.values();
  QList<QString> keys = data.keys();
  int valueCount = valueList.count();
  
  for(int i = 0; i < valueCount; i++)
  {
    const QVariant &val = valueList[i];
    
    switch(val.type()) {
    ...
    ...
    default:
      if(getTableName() == "student" && keys[i] == "name") 
      {
        std::string cipher = 
              BlowfishEncrypter.encrypt(StringUtil::fromQString(val.toString()));
        QByteArray byteArray(cipher.c_str(), cipher.length());
        query.addBindValue(byteArray.toHex());
      } else {
        query.addBindValue(val);
      }
      break;
     }
  }
}
```

The issue is, in the log file the decrypted studentName is shown as blank,

```
student name is:
```

and the "encrypted string: " line isn't even shown in the log file. Though there is no error or warning messages in the log file.
I also tested the BlowfishEncrypter class separately without involving the postgresSQL operations and can confirm its encrypt and decrypt function work as intended. So very likely I messed up during the string -> ByteArray -> hex conversion. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Use `psql` to look at the database and see what actually gets stored? that cuts the problem space in half. But honestly, you do not need to do the hex encoding. That is just for when you're entering the data inside the query itself. If you use a placeholder (as you do) you can just pass the plain binary data.

Comment: Also please (read)[https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qsqlquery.html#record] how to retrieve a row with QSqQuery from the database and properly check the return values of the functions.